# Struggling with File Upload in a VisualForce Page using Selenium WebDriver (ChromeDriver 2.12)

Tags: java, file, selenium, upload, visualforce

I need some help in working with a VisualForce File Upload dialog.  It works perfectly fine with Selenium IDE, but when I try to make it work with WebDriver, well, the driver can't even locate the elements, let alone work with them.

Here's the HTML code of the file uploader that I'm trying to test:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-xs-12">
File
<span class="required">*</span>
</label>
<div class="col-xs-12">
<input id="files" type="file" name="files">
</div>
</div>
```

Here's my Selenium IDE code that types a path to a file into the file uploader (it works great):

```
<td>type</td>
<td>id=files</td>
<td>C:\Users\filefolder\file.rtf</td>
```

Here's my Selenium WebDriver code (doesn't work):

```
try{
    driver.findElement(By.id("files")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\filefolder\\file.rtf");
}
catch(Exception e){
    verificationErrors.append("Could not work with file input; "+e.toString());
}
```

When I run it, here's the output:
java.lang.AssertionError: Could not work with file input; org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element

Please let me know if you need any more details in order to answer this.
Thanks a lot for your help here!!

Comment: Can you provide actual html of the page?

Comment: And this might be a typo but where are getting `]` of `files]` from?

Comment: You're right, Saifur.  That ending bracket was a typo.  I corrected it, but it still, unfortunately, doesn't work.  I added the HTML code relevant to the file dialog up above.  Let me know if you need anything else.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with a explicit wait and let me know if the page contains more than one element with `type='file'`

```
By locator = By.cssSelector("[type='file'][id='files']")
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\filefolder\\file.rtf");
```

Comment: Let me know if there is any exception